# Source code and figure each with individual labels side by side and aligned to the bottom

Tags: floats, minipage, minted

I am no latex expert and am trying to get get the following to work using the minipage package.
I have a source code section and an image and want to place them side by side.
Each of them should have it's own caption and they should align on the bottom edge, so that the captions align vertically as well.

Here is my current source code:

```
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{listing}[H]
\begin{minted}[style=monokai,bgcolor=monokaibg,linenos]{python}
shot.usd
#usda 1.0
(    
    subLayers = [        
        @shot_layout.usd@,
        @shot_sets.usd@
    ]
)
\end{minted}
\caption{Simple example of a primitive}
\label{lst:examplePrim}
\end{listing}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/pixar/sublayerArc.png}
  \caption{asset build process (batch)}
  \label{fig:department_overview}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
```

which results im some unreadable errors
[image]

EDIT: after the comment about minipage not supporting figures you could simply remove everything except includegraphics, but the result is still uncaptioned and not aligned properly. 
[image]

Comment: You can't place a float (`figure` in this case) insde of a `minipage`.

Comment: Ok, how would you solve this then?

Comment: This depends on the desired behaviour of the listing and figure. Do you want them to float (move where they fit best onto the page) or do you want them to stey where you used them in your code?

Comment: I'm fine with the later

Comment: To add a caption to the image, you can use `\captionof{figure}{...}` in addition with loading the `caption` package. To bottomalign the two adjacent minipages, use the optional argument as follows: `\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}`.

Comment: hey, thank you so much. If you post it as an answer I am going to accept it. Almost perfect, except for the bottom edge not aligning (listing and figure) Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have used `subfigure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{figure.jpg}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{image.jpg}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:image}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{(a) some random figure and (b) some random image} %% either use this for your caption or above or both
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In addition, please adjust width accordingly. :)

Greetings [image: My code says:]